# UItableview rows overlaps textfield

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, chat

I have view controller which has a tableview and below the table view there is a textfield(which is not part of tableview cell) and a button(just like whatsapp chat window) 
What I see is, when I start adding objects to the table, it grows up to the text field and grows beyond and below the text field at the bottom.

Comment: am i supposed to add textfield as a last row of the table?

Comment: Well, it is simple, in `viewDidLoad`, do this `bringSubViewToFront` , that bring your textfield and button to the front.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to go about it,

- In the IB, Make sure that your tableview comes before your textfield and button, The top most view is the farthest one.

  [image]
- You can use UIView methods such as

  1. sendSubviewToBack: (Send tableview to back)
  2. bringSubviewToFront: (Bring textfield and button to front)

Comment: i have a single view in which all the 3 are hosted - tableview,  textfield and button. this sounds like another neat approach. I hope one of the 2 suggestions works! Thanks

Comment: If all of them are in the same view, make sure UITableview is above the rest (in hierarchy window), that way it'll be behind the other views.

Comment: thanks @Abubakr. I'm re using the 3rd party library http://alexbarinov.github.io/UIBubbleTableView/  to do this. I have tried to change the height co-ordinates and changing the hierarchy. Did not help.. I need to get a fair understanding of this since the height values used are not appropriate in the code above, apart from the view overlap.

Comment: I'll be able to help you better if I can see your project; In any case if you change your mind about using some other third party, take a look at this, https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: thanks a lot for offering to help. Appreciate it much! I think the part of the code which is causing issue is -  [self.customView removeFromSuperview];
    self.customView = self.data.view;
    self.customView.frame = CGRectMake(x + self.data.insets.left, y + self.data.insets.top, width, height);
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.customView];  Also, they have weird scales. I would like to experiment JSQMessageViewcontroller ..looks better. I will ping you back if i want your help again! thanks once again...

Comment: Try writing [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:self.customView]; after
 [self.contentView addSubview:self.customView];

Comment: it so happens that once the text editing is done, code that executed has no control over the growing table rows. it just pushes the text field view down. so the table rows continue to grow south...text field and send button on top of the table rows ...

Comment: the known issues with the library captures the scroll issue. Some one claims he has fixed the issue, but it doesn't work https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView/pull/45

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting frames to each of these elements?

```
CGFloat tableViewHeight = 400;
self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view), tableViewHeight);
```

I'd place the textField and button as subviews to a view - self.textFieldElementsView and set the view's frame under the tableView:

```
self.textFieldElementsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMinX(self.tableView.frame) + tableViewHeight, CGRectGetWidth(self.view), CGRectGetHeight(self.view)-tableViewHeight);
```

Comment: I'm reusing the code from http://alexbarinov.github.io/UIBubbleTableView/  The logic they have used is bit different. If i don't get thru this issue, I'll stop using it and write my own.